# How to get the highlights data via GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

"Highlights" is a recently-released feature on GitHub (as shown in the following figure). I want to obtain the data of a certain user via GitHub API but cannot find any related APIs. Thanks a lot for providing help:)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not seem supported yet in the [GitHub API v3 user](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/)

The closest might be "[Get contextual information (hovercard) for a user](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-contextual-information-for-a-user)", but that does not include "highlights".